# Using $nin and $sample with mongdb aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a mongodb with a collection containing every song ever to be in the music charts. I've written a script that takes inputs of the number of songs I want and which year I want a random selection of songs from.  So far so good.

However, I'm trying to make it so as there are no repeated songs in the songs which are returned, which I'm trying to do by pushing the _id value of each song to an array as it's returned and then using $nin in the $match stage of the aggregation.

```
var getSongs = function(number, year, db, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection('songsList');
  var songIds = [];
  var chartSongs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    // Get one random document from the collection.
    collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { '_id': { '$nin': songIds }, 'songYear': year }
    },
    {
      $sample: { size: 1 }
    }
    ],
    function(err, chart) {
      songIds.push(chart[0]._id);
      chartSongs.push(chart[0]);
      if (songIds.length === number) {
        callback(chartSongs);
      }
    })
  }
};
```

However, although I'm getting the correct number of songs returned, I'm still getting repeated songs within that random list.

If anyone can offer a suggestion, or even offer me a better way of doing this, it  would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var getSongs = function(number, year, db, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection('songsList');
  collection.aggregate([                                                                                         
  {
    $match: { 'songYear': year } 
  },
  {
    $sample: { size: number } 
  }
  ],
  function(err, charts) { 
      callback(charts);
  });
};
```

Comment: That's kind of where I started. Unfortunately, although that will get me my certain number of results, that's not going to return me unique results - from the MongoDB docs: '$sample may output the same document more than once in its result set.'. I thought iterating $sample for the number of results I need and pushing each result's _id to an array to check against $nin should work, but it doesn't for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ebenezer66 Where are you reading that documentation quote? The [Actual Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior) is documented in that link. I think you are getting confused with documentation from `mapReduce` and the action of the `reducer` function.

Comment: It's on the link you provided, in the big red warning box at the foot of the behaviour section. However, I will concede that just using $sample size without all the loopy nonsense does seem to work in giving me non-repeated results. Could probably have saved myself an hour or two yesterday.

Comment: @ebenezer66 I think you are just not understanding what ["cursor isolation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-isolation) means, and you should have read the link in fact provided to that topic in the documentation. The whole case is that the document would actually need to be "modified" and "during" the process of fetching documents from the cursor in such a way that caused it to "move" on disk, and therefore "grow". Such cases of "growth" you really should be avoiding, and chances are your application never encounters this anyway.

Comment: @ebenezer66 The base chances on a relatively "small" sample size there would be basically negligable. At any rate, the "randomness" is certainly much higher than your own attempt to just grab "one random at a time", which would have a much higher probabilty of collision. So "premature optimization" applies here, and the simple process of selecting `n` in the `$sample` argument as suggested is the best approach.